# Casting comma separated integers as int[] in postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, casting

I have the following input: `,1,2,3`. I'd like to cast it to a `int[]` in postgres.

The following query works:

```
select string_to_array('1,2,3', ',')::int[]

-- => "string_to_array" => "{1,2,3}"
```

But this one doesn't:

```
select string_to_array(',1,2,3', ',')::int[]

-- => ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

This is because it tries to cast `''` (the first value) to an integer.

How can I ignore the first `,` (or any extra `,`) without an error ?

Comment: I think you wrote the same query twice.

Comment: @Marth Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Solution with postgres 9.3+ using [array_remove](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html) (see [Remove array values in pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072776/remove-array-values-in-pgsql))

```
select array_remove(string_to_array(',1,2,3', ','), '')::int[];

 -- array_remove
 --------------
 -- {1,2,3}
```

This will handle any amount of interspersed `,` in the array (eg: `1,2,,3`, `,1,,,2,3,`...)

Answer (score 4):

(Assuming the problem is leading/trailing `,` from the string)

Use [`trim`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html):

```
select string_to_array(trim(both ',' from ',1,2,3,'), ',')::int[];
┌─────────────────┐
│ string_to_array │
├─────────────────┤
│ {1,2,3}         │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

---

In case you want to also handle multiple ',' in a row, you can use `regexp_replace` (with the `g` (global) flag):

```
select string_to_array(
         trim(both ',' from regexp_replace(',1,,2,,,3', ',,+', ',', 'g')),
       ',')::int[];
┌─────────────────┐
│ string_to_array │
├─────────────────┤
│ {1,2,3}         │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

---

To also have the empty string return `NULL`, use `NULLIF(<string>, '')`:

```
select string_to_array(trim(both ',' from regexp_replace(NULLIF('', ''), ',,+', ',', 'g')), ',')::int[];
┌─────────────────┐
│ string_to_array │
├─────────────────┤
│ (null)          │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yes great suggestions. I'm wondering if there is a way of specifying: `treat the empty string as null when casting to int[]`